# I get this error when I run "bundle install" with gem 'pg'. what should i do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error when I try to bundle install with pg gem. I already install postgresql gem. Please tell me what can I do? I saw the other Stackoverlfow posts and implemented them but it's still showing this error

when the bundler tries to run gem pg

```
Installing pg (0.17.1) 
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/salmanalam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb   
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or               libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or      libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/salmanalam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pg-    0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86_64-   linux/2.0.0/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Do you use Postgre database ? If you use Mysql, Sqlite you can comment this line in Gemfile

Comment: u need to change your /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf file, replace "md5" to "trust" in this file. everywhere.

Comment: How do I do that @Rahul?

Comment: from termial type $ sudo gedit /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf , make edits and save. not sure if this will fix your problem.

Comment: dont forget to restart postgres $ sudo service postgresql restart

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are on Linux.

Try installing `libpq-dev` for Debian/Ubuntu, or `postgresql-devel` for RHEL systems.

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get install libpq-dev. Didn't solve the problem, still the same error